# stack added but not separately

Tags: java, stack

```
public class New1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x = 0;
      int cost = 1;
      int y = 0;
      int g = 0;
      Stack<Stack<Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();//stackk within stack
      Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<>();
      s1.push(x);
      s1.push(y);
      s1.push(g);
      stack.push(s1);
      System.out.println("before function calling"+stack);
      int [] b=fun1(x,y,g,cost);//Here is error
      System.out.println(x);//But x doesn't hold this value it is zero          
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));//print the value that return by a[]
      s1.push(x);
      s1.push(y);
      s1.push(g);
      System.out.println("After function calling"+stack);
  }
  public static int[] fun1(int d, int b, int c,int f) {
      int [] a=new int[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          int x2=1,y2=1,g2=1;
          d = x2 + f;
          b = y2 + f;
          c = g2 + f;
          a[0]=d;
          a[1]=b;
          a[2]=c;
      }//want to push the updated value into the stack s1.
      return (a);
  }
}
```

Stack can give the output like that `[[0,0,0][2,2,2]]` but didn't. Also whenever the s1 value will be update it will push on main stack like individual. Means if my for loop run for 2nd time and the value will be [3,3,3]. It remains on the same main stack like `[[0,0,0],[2,2,2][3,3,3]]`. But the all are merged like `[0,0,0,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.

Didn't produce the desired output and cannot find the bug.

Comment: a little advice, you should choose better names for your variables. Names like  `a`, `x` and `x2` get real confusing, real fast.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain more clearly what your code is trying to do? It would also help to see a few clear examples of an input, your expected output, and your actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Your code is currently just adding x,y,g to the stack twice so the output is [0,0,0,0,0,0]. You are never using the new values returned by the function f. If you push the values returned by function f to a new stack and then add that stack to the stack named "stack" then you will get the desired output that is [[0,0,0][2,2,2]].
 Please comment if I understood it right.

Comment: Yeah You got it right.I don't want to push the new value return by function fun() in a new stack.I want to push it in the same stack with the previous one. Is it possible in stack data structure? If not then which data structure is suitable for this operation? and 2nd think I return the value using return(a) in my program. Then call fun() function in my main function.So how could I use it? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Iam unable to understand your usecase. It will be best if you give me the input and expected output with few cases and I will be best able to help you with the suggestions.